# nextLine().charAt(0) inside a switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm making a very basic calculator program and ran into a problem that's baffled my mind the entire time.

Code:

```
switch(operation){
      case 'a':
      case 'A':
          addition(n);
          operation = n.nextLine().charAt(0);
          break;
```

When I run the program and enter either characters (proceeding code uses Scanner object n to determine which char I type in), the method addition(n) works as intended. Basically the switch statement is inside a while loop so that it executes until I enter 'E', and the 5th line in the code I have above will change the char operation so that it does not execute the addition switch block over and over. The 5th line `operation = n.nextLine().charAt(0);` will give me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
```

Why is it giving me this error? What troubles my mind more is my default inside the switch is structured similarily yet the exact same code will work for it.

```
  default:
      System.out.println("Invalid entry. Refer to above menu and input"
              + " your choice of operation.");
      operation = n.nextLine().charAt(0);
      break;
```

Many thanks for your time.

EDIT: If I comment out the method `addition(n)`, the 5th line will work as fine, allowing me to change my char operation. Why is the 4th line responsible for this?

Comment: What happens when `n.nextLine()` returns an empty string?

Comment: Then charAt(0) would return an error since there is no character to obtain. It does not give me an option to input something in the next line, and instead gives the error straight away. This isn't the case for the default part of the code.

Comment: It won't 'return an error', it will *throw* the *exception you are getting.*

Comment: @JohnnyBoy The point of the comment was to get you to think about the line of code in question, and how it's written... Since you _can_ get an empty string from `n.nextLine()` and calling `charAt()` on it _will_ produce the above exception, you need to reconsider calling `.charAt(0)` on it until you've validated the result.

Comment: So what would be better to call for this situation?

Comment: @JohnnyBoy you need to validate the returned string is not empty before you call `charAt()` on it. `String line = n.nextLine(); if ( !line.equals("") ) { char c = line.charAt(0); ... }`

Comment: Thank you for your help. My program can now run in a loop, free of errors. Testing it beforehand solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `n.next().charAt(0)` instead of  `n.nextLine().charAt(0)`. I think beacuse our task is to read the first character why should I consider a whole line of text may contain many words, spaces, special characters etc. , while I can get the first character from the first word and it is efficient, that's why java does not allow. :)

Welcome !